# helm-grep-do-git-grep : show only exact matching

Tags: helm-grep

Windows 10, Emacs 25, Helm
I want to find exact text "**data autoupdate**" in all files in some folder in my Android Git project.

So I use command

```
M-x helm-grep-do-git-grep
```

And input text "**data autoupdate**"

Here result:

[image]

As you can see it find 4 candiates. 
But I not need first candidate. I need exact matches.
So the candidates must be 3.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Search for :

> data\ autoupdate

Then it would only return rows where "data" is immediately followed by a space and then "autoupdate"

Comment: Not help. If I use "data\ autoupdate" the result is zero candidates.